# Flutter UI not updating with new data

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've built an friendship app using Flutter, where the user receives a new friendship match once every week. In the meantime, the match screen shows a countdown to the next match. I'm using the flutter_countdown_timer library for timer. Both the 'new match' and 'time to next match' are updated in the Firebase collection, and are automatically reflected in the app by listening for DB changes through Firebase snapshots.

Problem: This works fine, while testing. However, the 'time to next match' or 'new match' do not get updated on the app if I update the DB after a certain delay [Say 1+ days]. I'm not sure why this happens - I'm setting the state for every new update in the DB and not unsubscribing from the Firebase snapshot. Any thoughts?

Here's a snippet of how I fetch / listen for the time to next match [The method to fetch / listen for a new match is similar, and both update the UI via the setState function]

```
getTimeToNextMatch() async {

  return FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection("endTime")
      .doc(“docID”)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((result) {

        setState(() {
          timeToNextMatch = result.data()['timeToNextMatch'];
          isLoading = false;
        });

      });
}
```

I've tried sending an invalid countdown time or match - but none of them reproduce this issue. Also note that this issue takes place even if the app is left dormant and the DB is updated after a few days.

Comment: Additional context - I can reproduce this error by bringing the app from background to foreground after 1+ hour, in which case all firebase operations fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
late StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> _subscription;

Future<void> getTimeToNextMatch() async {
  try {
    _subscription = FirebaseFirestore
      .instance
      .collection("endTime")
      .doc("docID")
      .snapshots()
      .listen((result) {
        if (result.hasData) {
          setState(() {
            timeToNextMatch = result.data()['timeToNextMatch'];
            isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      }, onError: (error) {
        print('Error: $error');
      }, onDone: () {
        print('Stream closed');
      });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _subscription?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed - Is the recommendation to include a try/catch to monitor errors?